# How to have a default text if ng-bind or {{}} is blank

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind a `scope` variable with `<span>` and i am trying to display some default text if the scope variable is blank.I tried using `ng-bind` and `{{}}` but could not find a solution.[This](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/h4ehecc0/1/) is an illustration of the issue

Here is my controller

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope) {
$scope.level = "iResult";
$scope.reset =function(){
    $scope.level = "";
};
```

Here is the template

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="tableForVxp" class="dataDisplay2">
{{level}}
<button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
<p>On click of reset the level get updated as blank and if its blank i want a default text "NoneLeft" to be displayed</p>
```

I am not looking for solutions using `ng-if,ng-show,ng-hide` .

Comment: here is a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/h4ehecc0/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use OR operator inside of binding expression:

```
{{level || 'NoneLeft'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{level.length>0?level:'NoneLeft'}}
```